# How to add row to form using Angular and onClick function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I have looked at the previous answers and know the solution lies with ng-repeat however I think I am having problems with my click function and/or the structure of the data. I have an controller object named controller.addCPR which has a bunch of properties from a DB query.

What I'm trying to do is duplicate one row with 3 of those properties in a form using a click function. Using the ng repeat the row has just repeated itself but the add button still does nothing. Any help is appreciated here is my attempt.

**The controller object setting defaults**

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('globalAdmin.states_3')
    .controller('AddCPRModalController', AddCPRModalController);

     AddCPRModalController.$inject = ['$uibModalInstance', 'StatesService'];

     function AddCPRModalController($uibModalInstance, StatesService) { 

     controller.addCPR = {
        alert: 'No',
        weight: 10,
        status: 'y',
        dte: new Date()
     };

     controller.onAddRowClick = function () {
        var row = {
            url: controller.addCPR.url,
            type: controller.addCPR.type,
            dynamic: controller.addCPR.dynamic
        };
        controller.addCPR.push(row)
        console.log('clicked');
     };

     //other controller functions not listed here

   }
})();
```

**The html of the row I am trying to duplicate on click in the form**

```
<div ng-repeat="row in controller.addCPR" class="form-group row add-row" ng-class="{'has-danger': addCPRForm.url.$dirty && addCPRForm.url.$invalid}">
  <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputDate">URL(s):</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" class="states-url" ng-model="controller.addCPR.url" placeholder="Enter URL's here">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <label>Type:
      <div class="type-dropdown">
          <select ng-model="controller.addCPR.type">
              <option value="html">HTML</option>
              <option value="pdf">PDF</option>
              <option value="csv">CSV</option>
              <option value="xls">XLS</option>
              <option value="txt">TXT</option>
              <option value="dbf">DBF</option>
              <option value="doc">DOC</option>
              <option value="sas">SAS</option>
              <option value="ppt">PPT</option>
              <option value="png">PNG</option>
              <option value="jpg">JPG</option>
          </select>
      </div>
  </label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <label>Dynamic:
      <div class="dynamic-dropdown">
          <select ng-model="controller.addCPR.dynamic">
              <option value="n">No</option>
              <option value="y">Yes</option>
          </select>
      </div>
  </label>
  </div>
  <button class="addRow" ng-click="controller.onAddRowClick()">+</button><button class="removeRow"
    ng-click="onRemoveRowClick()">-</button>
</div>
```

**EDIT--------------------------------------**

I figured out my own question I hope the answer may help someone else.

first I modified the ng-repeat on the row to be `row in controller.rows track by $index`

secondly in my controller I created a new array with the properties to match the ng-repeat

```
controller.rows = [
   {url: '', type: '', dynamic: ''},
];
```

lastly I modified the click function to be

```
controller.onAddRowClick = function() {
        var row = {
            url : '',
            type : '',
            dynamic : ''
        };
        controller.rows.push(row);
        console.log('clicked');
    };
```

Now the row is being added on click as expected. Thanks to everyone for their input.

Comment: `controller.addPCR`  is an object, not an array. Is that a typo in the question? I ask since you are calling `push` on it which would explode.

Comment: @AluanHaddad no its an object which I am using to set defaults on other properties in the form

Comment: `controller.addCPR.push(row)`... You should get an error in your console for that

Comment: @AluanHaddad no error not even getting back 'clicked' from the console log

Comment: What code encloses your `controller` object?

Comment: @AluanHaddad just the instantiation of the controller like so 

(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('globalAdmin.states_3')
        .controller('AddCPRModalController', AddCPRModalController);

    AddCPRModalController.$inject = ['$uibModalInstance', 'StatesService'];

    function AddCPRModalController($uibModalInstance, StatesService) {   

    }
})();

Comment: add that to your question (with formatting). Also, howm is the controller attached, via a component? via ng-controller? via a route?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Sure, I'm using routes via angular-ui-router

Comment: and state looks like this: `.state({ controller: 'AddCPRModalController', controllerAs: 'controller'})`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143906/discussion-between-gwar9-and-aluan-haddad).